# Get signatures for address including SPL transfers

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program

I would like to check who has transferred a certain SPL token to a given wallet. But when i try to filter all transactions the SPL token transfers are not included.

```
recent_transactions = await client.get_signatures_for_address(
            public_key, 
            before=None, 
            until=None, 
            limit=1000
)
```

Any idea why only the transactions are gathered from the "Transactions" and the "SPL Transfer" transactions are not included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to look for the token accounts of these wallets. On Solana tokens are stored in token accounts.

A token account is usually derived from the wallet address, the associated token program and the mint of the token. This is then called the associated token account.

In js you can get the associated token account like this:

```
const associatedTokenAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress
(
    tokenMint,
    keyPair.publicKey,
    false,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
);
```

If you look for changes of that account you will see the changes of the spl token.

(There can also be token accounts which are not derived from the associated token program. These you would need to find differently)

Comment: You are right indeed, tbh i didn't know the tokens were stored on a different address. When i filter on the associated address then i am able to get the transactions. Thanks for the quick help!